# Encoding from a textarea tag

Tags: php, html, encoding, webforms, textarea

Suppose in a form, you type within a textarea the character `"ぎ"`

At the momment of submit the text and send it to another page that will process it (i.e. `action="site.php"`):
Will the page that send the text encode that text? 
or the page that recieve the text?

The point is: the form send the characters encoded(sequences of bytes) or characters to be encoded by the page that recieve that text from the form.

Is the page encoded again when is going to be sended a form?
Cuz the text that will be typed is not part of the source code previously encoded.

Comment: wow thats repetitive, repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to UTF8 encode that

Look at [utf8_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and [utf8_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

You'll also want to look into [multibyte-safe functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)

Comment: Yeah but i wanna know how the form send that characters, encoded or non-encoded characters

Comment: Set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and your UTF characters should be passed literally. You'll then need to `utf8_encode()` it when you insert it into your database, and `utf8_decode()` it when you display it later.

Comment: Its fixed, thank you. but i've tried adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form and it pass the chars as bytes encoded by the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` tag, i dont think that the characters can be passed literally. But thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The page that sends the text is in charge of the encoding, which as you specify can by changed by the meta charset.

Comment: So the page is going to be encoded again when you submit the form. cuz that text is not a part of the source code(is not encoded)

Comment: a bit late, but this actually helped me, since I hadn't declared the charset of my web page to be utf-8 it was sending as escaped html and then my php was escaping again leading to incorrect output. +1